# How To Register New User Using Dwolla API

Tags: dwolla

This started as a question, but in the process of posting this question, I solved it.  So now, this is an FYI post...

==========

At first, whenever I tried to post to this URL, I would get an error message:

- https:// www.dwolla.com/oauth/rest/register --> Bad URL

  There is no operation listening for
  http:// phx-dwol-web1.cloudworks.com/oauth/rest/register, but there is
  an operation listening for
  http:// www.dwolla.com/oauth/rest/register/, so you are being
  redirected there.

I fixed by appending the auth values to the post URL:

- https://www.dwolla.com/oauth/rest/register/?client_id={id}&client_secret={secret}
  --> Good URL

Then, I was having trouble with request formatting.  To fix this, make sure that you post JSON in the BODY of the post.  Do NOT append to the URL, or submit as form fields.

Lastly, when I finally got a proper response from the Dwolla API, I was getting this error:

- "New user must accept terms of service."

This is because the Dwolla API is CASE SENSITIVE, so the "ACCEPTTERMS" parameter in the JSON body must be submitted as "acceptTerms" in order for it to work.

Here is the documentation I am referencing:
http://developers.dwolla.com/dev/docs/register

Happy coding!

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, but SO doesn't work in the same way a standard board does. Please see the [FAQ], and happy coding!

Comment: Self-answered questions are definitely great, but could you please post your "issue/problem" as the question, and then your "solution/process" as an answer?

Comment: So lets down vote the new user who's trying to be helpful and make him feel right at home...

Comment: Personally this helped save me a lot of time, as I was running into the same issue, and I think that's what SO should be about, helping people...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer...it ultimately led to me solving my problem as well.

For completeness, I encountered this error when sending a poorly formed request to the api, where I had left off the trailing / before the get parameter {oauth_token}.

INCORRECT:

```
http://www.dwolla.com/oauth/rest/users?oauth_token={oauth_token}
```

CORRECT:

```
http://www.dwolla.com/oauth/rest/users/?oauth_token={oauth_token}
```